# Selecting and printing out duplicates in SQL? (No duplicate)

Tags: mysql, sql

The question looks like a duplicate because I have found a lot of answers related to this but even thought I tried everything, nothing answered my problem.

I want to select all the rows which have the same value(category_max). I have tried this query:

```
SELECT w1.user_name, w1.wallet_adr, w1.category_min, w1.category_max,
w2.user_name, w2.wallet_adr, w2.category_min, w2.category_max
FROM WaitingPlayers w1, WaitingPlayers w2
WHERE w1.category_max = w2.category_max
AND w1.wallet_adr <> w2.wallet_adr
```

I have also tried it with inner join as you can see here:

```
SELECT 
w1.user_name, w1.wallet_adr, w1.category_min, w1.category_max,
w2.user_name, w2.wallet_adr, w2.category_min, w2.category_max
FROM WaitingPlayers w1
INNER JOIN WaitingPlayers w2 ON w2.category_max = w1.category_max 
WHERE w2.wallet_adr != w1.wallet_adr
```

But the result is always the same:

http://i61.tinypic.com/10nyus3.png

This is what I want:

http://i60.tinypic.com/2lvxjk.png

Wallet_adr and username are unique so they really should not be displayed twice unless that selection w1 and w2 is considered as select twice.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a group by:

```
 WHERE w2.wallet_adr != w1.wallet_adr 
 GROUP BY w1.user_name
```

EDIT: instead of

```
  SELECT w1.user_name, w1.wallet_adr, w1.category_min, w1.category_max,
  w2.user_name, w2.wallet_adr, w2.category_min, w2.category_max
  FROM ...
```

use

```
 SELECT w1.user_name, w1.wallet_adr, w1.category_min, w1.category_max
 FROM ....
```

Comment: Almost perfect, it helped to remove 3 last rows but there are still 4 columns in the end which are not supposed to be there. I mean wallet adr, username, category min and category max is there second time.

Comment: the columns you need to select what you want.

Comment: You are right, I just needed to select w1.wallet_adr etc not w2.bla bla.

Comment: yes select what you want . and remove what you dont want from select.

Comment: Could you advice me how to remove those selected after selection?

Comment: if you select them you can just dont fetch them in php or the language you using. or simply remove them from the select

Comment: how to remove from select please? Thats what I am asking. Would you be so kind? :)

Answer (score 2):

This has all pairs, which could get quite large:

```
SELECT w1.user_name, w1.wallet_adr, w1.category_min, w1.category_max,
       w2.user_name, w2.wallet_adr, w2.category_min, w2.category_max
FROM WaitingPlayers w1 join
     WaitingPlayers w2
     on w1.category_max = w2.category_max AND
     w1.wallet_adr <> w2.wallet_adr;
```

I imagine the following would be more useful:

```
select wp.*
from WaitingPlayers wp join
     (select wp.category_max, count(*) as cnt
      from WaitingPlayers wp
      group by wp.category_max
      having cnt > 1
     ) wpcnt
     on wp.category_max = wpcnt.category_max
order by cnt desc, wp.category_max;
```

If you need for the duplicates to have more than one `wallet_adr`, change the subquery to:

```
select wp.*
from WaitingPlayers wp join
     (select wp.category_max, count(distinct wp.wallet_adr) as cnt
      from WaitingPlayers wp
      group by wp.category_max
      having cnt > 1
     ) wpcnt
     on wp.category_max = wpcnt.category_max
order by cnt desc, wp.category_max;
```

This will put duplicates on a separate line.

Comment: The only problem is I don't get it at all... but no worries you have done your part :D